# How to conditionally compile C code based on size of data?

Tags: c

I define below data type:

```
typedef int MyInt;
```

Then I hope to define a new data type based on size of MyInt, something like below code, but I can't find a solution for it.

```
#if sizeof(MyInt) == 2
    typedef long MyLong;
#else
    typedef short MyLong;
#endif
```

Could anybody help?

Comment: Preprocessor and code evaluation (`sizeof(...)`) are different compilation steps.

Comment: Calling a `short` a `MyLong` seems a bit odd...

Comment: This is not possible, cuz you need to declare a variable before compilation not during runtime. But you can always use `type casting`to change the variable's data type

Comment: Thanks, I actually know that. So do you mean there is no way for such case?

Comment: Do you want it to be portable across compilers?

Comment: Perhaps you could use some fixed-size types defined in stdint.h, like `uint8_t`, `uint16_T`, ... instead of conditional compilation ?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be portable across compilers.

Comment: Above code is just sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the preprocessor's job to evaluate `sizeof`, that's done by the compiler which is a later stage in the process. Evaluating `sizeof` needs deep C knowledge that the preprocessor simply doesn't have.

You could (in theory) consider the preprocessor as a separate step, that does *text only* transforms, in effect converting "foo.c" to "foo-preprocessed.c". The latter file won't have any `#include` or `#if`s left, they're all evaluated and replaced by the preprocessor. The actual compiler never sees them.

You should consider using `<stdint.h>` and the known-precision types (`uint16_t` and friends).

Comment: Is 'stdint.h' standard C99 heander file or compiler dependent?

Comment: @Vincent : yes it is part of C99, and supported by standards compliant compilers.

Comment: @vincent, it's also supported by a lot of nonstandard compilers. Types such as `int16_t` and `uint32_t` etc where in fact standardized because of their nearly ubiquitous use. Some nonstandard compilers have these types declared in some other header if they don't have `stdint.h`.

Comment: The #if directive is in fact not processing text (which would be very useful sometimes) but integer expressions.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the values of macros such as `UINT_MAX` to determine the size of the underlying type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UINT_MAX` - it can give you a clue about the size of integer.

```
#if (UINT_MAX <= 65536)
    typedef long MyLong;
#else
    typedef short MyLong;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

New-enough GCC (I think 4.3) has predefined identifiers like `__SIZEOF_LONG__`, but it is simpler to just use the constants in `limits.h` as suggested by others.

Answer (score 0):

Although I and the C preprocessor are sworn enemies, we sometimes need each other ;). So I would propose:

```
#if SIZEOF_MYINT == 2
#   define MYLONG_T long
#elif SIZEOF_MYINT == 4
#   define MYLONG_T short
#endif

typedef MYLONG_T MyLong;
```

Somewhere else (in a global config header file) you have your architecture dependent

```
#define SIZEOF_MYINT 2
```